# Uncaught TypeError: Class extends value #<Object> is not a constructor or null - with superagent-throttle

Tags: javascript, typescript, vite, superagent

I am trying to import the npm package superagent-throttle in my `TypeScript` project, but when I do so I get this message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Class extends value #<Object> is not a constructor or null
```

If I use `require` it works fine:

```
const Throttle = require("superagent-throttle");
```

But, I've started using `Vite` which does not allow `require` so I have to use `import` instead.

The code where I reference it wants to instantiate a `class` ie:

```
        this.throttle = new Throttle({
            // set false to pause queue
            active: true,
            // how many requests can be sent every `ratePer`
            rate: 10000,
            // number of ms in which `rate` requests may be sent
            ratePer: 1000,
            // How many requests can be sent concurrently
            concurrent: 2
        });
```

I have tried different variations of the `import` statement, but none of these work for me:

```
import { Throttle } from "superagent-throttle";
import Throttle from "superagent-throttle";
import * as Throttle from "superagent-throttle";
```

They all give the same result - they compile ok but fail at runtime with the same error message (as above).

The code in the `superagent-throttle` JS file looks rather obscure, I have no idea what it's trying to do, so I'm struggling to try and understand how I could fix this issue:

Package file: `node_modules/superagent-throttle/dist/index.js`:

```
'use strict';

var _events = require('events');

var _events2 = _interopRequireDefault(_events);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }
...
class Throttle extends _events2.default {
  constructor(options) {
    super();
    // instance properties
    this._options({
      _requestTimes: [0],
      _current: 0,
      _buffer: [],
      _serials: {},
      _timeout: false
    });
... etc ...
```

Comment: What version of superagent-throttle do you have installed?

Comment: `import Throttle from "superagent-throttle"` works fine [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-jepsen-etjmr?file=/src/index.ts). It's missing type definitions though (ie never built for Typescript). Perhaps you'd be better off finding a more actively developed library

Comment: @Phil I'm using version 1.0.1, which is the latest (but published 3 years ago). I've looked for an alternative, but can't find anything else that will limit concurrent requests. I would write my own TypeScript type file for superagent-throttle - but I don't know how to do it for a library with such a complicated interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message points to `_events2.default` in the offending code:

```js
var _events = require('events');

var _events2 = _interopRequireDefault(_events);
⋮                                 /* not a constructor or null */
class Throttle extends _events2.default {
```

The debugger reveals that `_events.default` is stubbed as an empty object, which means the `events` module is not available. `events` (from [Node](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html)) is normally unavailable in the browser, leading to the error you observed.

One solution is to install an [`events`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/events) shim:

```
npm i -S events
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vite-superagent-throttle)